# How to resolve error in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.04, package-management, aptitude

I'm using Ubuntu 9.04. When I run any command like `sudo apt-get update`, I get following error message:

```
E: Type 'l.com/ubuntu' is not known on line 45 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Due to this problem I'm not able to download anything. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You've to edit the source list `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

thus, go to terminal and type `sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`. Delete the offending line, ctrl+o to save, ctrl+x to exit.

Comment: You either meant to type `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list` or those keyboard shortcuts were an accident.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you've accidentally pressed Enter in the middle of the line #44 and created a new line #45 with invalid format. Check those lines.